# Automate UI testing with Javascript, node - starting & stopping a web server

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, phantomjs, ui-automation

I'm currently investiagating automated UI testing using JavaScript on windows with node.js and phantom.js and unsurprisingly I've found many frameworks that can help in this regard ([casper.js](http://casperjs.org/), Buster.js, etc).

The one thing that seems to be missing from the frameworks I have looked at so far is stopping and starting a web server to server the web pages so that testing framework can perform its testing.  One exception is [WebDriver.js](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) which uses the [Selenium standalone server](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#selenium-server) but this relies on a server written Java and at  the moment I'd prefer to find a node based solution if at all possible.

From the node perscpective I've looked at [Connect.js](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) and also [Http-Server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server) (which I particularly like) but the issue is starting and stopping these from a JavaScript test.

I've attempted to create a casper.js test that would interact with a server, run the test and then stop the server but I can't get it to work, here's an example script

```
var childProcess = require('child_process').spawn('http-server', '/TestSite');

casper.test.begin("Load-page", 1, function suite(test){

    casper.start('http://localhost:8080/',function(){
        test.assertTitle("test page");
    });

    casper.run(function(){
        test.done();
        childProcess.kill();
    });
});
```

I call this from the command line using the following command (casper is in my Path variable):

```
casperjs Load-page testFile.js
```

What I was hoping would happen is the http-server would start, casper would start the test and then after the test was run the http-server would be killed.

I've also tried similar with Connect:

```
var server= connect.createServer(connect.static('/TestSite')).listen(8080)

casper.test.begin("Load-page", 1, function suite(test){

    casper.start('http://localhost:8080/',function(){
        test.assertTitle("test page");
    });

    casper.run(function(){
        test.done();
        server.stop();
    });
});
```

But again with no luck.

I can run the Casper sample tests which work and I've also got Node in my Path as well and can call the REPL from the command prompt.

The directory structure is:

Code
  /TestSite
  /node_modules

and I run the tests from the Code folder.

Am I simply unable to do this or am I just not getting how it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using a combination of differebt scripts and using child_process spawn.

I created a script called `startServer.js` that would start the server using Connect:

```
var connect = require('connect');

var server= connect.createServer(connect.static('TestSite'));

server.listen(8081);
```

I created another script `runTests.js` that would call the server script via spawn and then call Casper, again via spawn, and run all the capser tests that are in a folder called tests relative to where the script is run from.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var stillRunning = true;

var server = child_process.spawn('node', ['createServer.js']);

var casper = child_process.spawn('casperjs', ['test tests']);

casper.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data.toString());
});

casper.stderr.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});

casper.on('exit', function(code){
    server.kill();
    process.exit(0);
});
```

To use this at the command prompt navigate to the folder where the script is and then run `node runTests.js` and the server will be started and the tests run against the site

Answer (score 0):

When you say "no luck" what do you mean?

The connect example looks mostly OK, and I'd prefer it over spawning a subprocess. Bear in mind that `listen` is potentially async so the server might not be available immediately though.  The second param to `listen` is a callback that will be run once the server is listening - maybe try running the tests in that callback instead?

Pro Tip: Don't rely on port 8080 always being free on whatever machine you're running on - passing in `0` for the port will cause the server to start on a random port, you can then do `server.address().port` in the `listen` callback to get the port that was chosen

Comment: I just noticed you're using windows, the `0` thing might not work there, YMMV

Comment: I get a ReferenceError Can't find variable process C:/GitHub/TestSite/node_modules/connect/index.js:2

Comment: Ok, I completely missed the obvious problem here - [casperjs isn't nodejs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-casperjs-a-node-js-library)

Comment: It sounds like you want to drive Casper from a node module, that link references spooky js, but I've never used it (or Casper tbh)